# get instagram's like/follow button response

Tags: php, ajax, instagram

There is a website which allows "following" and "liking" Instagram's pages without an access-token.
It has a button, which when you click on it, it opens a new window of someone's Instagram page, and if you follow him/her and close the Instagram page they understand that you followed the page.  How is this possible?

Here is their sample code :

```
<script>
    function func(){
        FBLL_671661 = window.open('getulr.php?i=JTIxMTglRTQlREUlMTAlOTElODQlMTF6JUUzJTg5JTIwWiUzRCUzQyVDNSVCMDclOUQ=','FB_671661',status=0,toolbar=0,width=550,height=195);
        if(FBLL_671661.closed){
            confirmSingleFB(671661, "simeumesmo", "31084ff3990fe6142306251b671661", "19", 0, "UV9W49wV%2FowWe%2BaHIkEwMsDaWfvZfnZkmRS8XOk6GlyALO%2Bpg8Q%2BwWhyXUA%3D", "10","simeumesmo");
        }
    }

    function confirmSingleFB(id,url,linkId,network,isPriority,code,cpc,link_title){
        url=encodeURIComponent(url);
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"./ajax.php",
            data:'act=checkFollowed&params={"id":"'+id+'","url":"'+url+'", "network":"'+network+'", "link_id":"'+linkId+'", "IXY5pZpE":"'+code+'", "cpc":"'+cpc+'", "title":"'+link_title+'"}',
            success:function(result){
                $(container).html(result);}
        });
    }
</script>


<button onclick=func()> follow </button>
```

simeumesmo is the person's username that have to follow.
obviously I have no idea what is behind the geturl.php and ajax.php

Comment: Wait. What? Is there anything that YOU have tried?

Comment: excuse me , what do you mean?

Comment: you just pasted their example code- so he's asking if you've written any code

Comment: oh , no is't not the exact code.parametrs have several thing like username of page , ...

Comment: @nomistic it's the exact code